# ruby adding range elements in each block

Tags: ruby, range, block

How can I add range elements in each block together.  E.g.:

```
a = [[1..10, 13..20, 21..24], [34..39, 42..45], [50..55]]
```

outcome:

```
a = [[9+7+3],[5+3],[5]]
a = [20, 8, 5]
```

Comment: Why does `1..10` equal 10, but `13..20` equal 7? The latter should be 8 IMO  . . . ? But you have done this consistently for everything except 1..10?

Comment: Yes sorry I've changed it.  It should be 10-1, 20-13 etc..

Comment: So you want to sum 1 less than the number of entries from each Range?

Comment: not sure what you mean there, but I like to sum ((10-1)+(20-13)+(24-21)), etc

Comment: ok, have you looked at any Ruby methods on Array? What seems to be the problem?

Comment: Im not sure how you will add up ranges within an element in an array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access the first and last elements of a range by the corresponding `first` and `last` methods. `inject(:+)` sums up the partial distances of all the ranges belonging to the same group.

```
a.map { |ran­ges| range­s.map { |rang­e| range­.last - range­.first }.inj­ect(:+) }
=> [19, 8, 5]
```

Or, even shorter, as suggested by tokland using Ruby 2.0:

```
a.map { |ran­ges| range­s.map(&:size).reduce(0, :+) }
```

Answer (score 1):

Ruby 2.0:

```
a.map { |ranges| ranges.map { |r| r.size - 1 } .reduce(0, :+) }
```

Comment: This doesn't give the desired result

Answer (score 0):

`Range` class has a method called [`#size`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Range.html#method-i-size). Thus we can do as :

```
a.map { |ranges| ranges.inject(0) { |sum,rng| sum + rng.size - 1 } }
```